# Dynamic operator in Hibernate filters

Tags: java, hibernate, dynamic, filter

I have a requirement to define a custom hibernate filter at runtime in essence which I'm not sure is possible.

Basically the user is going to be passing in an object representing the filter which is defined by the following schema -

```
<attributeGroup name="FilterAttributes">
        <attribute name="Name" type="string" use="required"/>
        <attribute name="Operation" type="string" use="required"/>
        <attribute name="Value" type="string" use="required"/>
    </attributeGroup>
    <complexType name="Filter">
        <attributeGroup ref="F:FilterAttributes"/>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="FilterCriteria">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Filter" type="F:Filter" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="FilterCriteria" type="F:FilterCriteria"/>
```

So the idea is the user would pass in an object representing this structure and I'd create a filter on the fly - the name of the property / db column to filter on, the operator to use in the comparison, and the value to compare against.

I know I can define my filters and parameterize the values inside my HBM or using annotations, but that won't let me change the operator at runtime. I'd be fine defining a filter for every column we plan to allow filtering on, but I'd rather not have to specify one for every possible operator the user could pass in.

Is it possible to construct / modify a filter at runtime so I could make this happen?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're editing my posts to "remove unnecessary sentences" but please stop. I'm the native English speaker here, I don't need a grammar nazi following me around on stackoverflow thank you very much.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/160043